# C++ Add compiler warnings for wrong usage of custom print/log function

Tags: c++, printing, format, compiler-warnings

I've got the following function and I'd like to have warnings as one has when using printf:

```
void LoggingManager::log(int32_t logLevel, const char *p_str, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, p_str);
    vsnprintf(s_LogginManagerBuffer, LOGGING_MANAGER_BUFFER_SIZE - 1, p_str, args);
    va_end(args);

    internalLog(s_LogginManagerBuffer);
}
```

I'd like to somehow have warnings if I forget to add an argument for one of the tokens in the format-string. Also warnings for having too many (or wrong arguments) would be awesome.
I recently faced some crashes due to forgetting an argument in the logging function.

If it's not possible to do it this way, how could I rewrite my function, to have warnings but the same functionality?

Comment: Please don't tag with c, this is not valid c code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using gcc/g++/clang you can use the *format* attribute as specified on [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

> format (archetype, string-index, first-to-check)
>
> The format attribute specifies that a function takes printf, scanf, strftime or strfmon style arguments that should be type-checked against a format string. For example, the declaration:
>
> `extern int my_printf (void *my_object, const char *my_format, ...)
>         __attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)));`
>
> causes the compiler to check the arguments in calls to my_printf for consistency with the printf style format string argument my_format.

It doesn't matter whether the `__attribute__` is before or after the function prototype.

So in your case you can do something like this:

```
class LoggingManager {
    ...
public:
    void log(int32_t logLevel, const char *p_str, ...) __attribute__((format (printf, 3, 4)));
    ...
};
```

Note that because this is a member function you need to account for the implicit `this` parameter passed. So the format string would actually be the 3rd argument instead of the 2nd. (`format (printf, 3, 4)` instead of `format (printf, 2, 3)`)

See it work [here](https://godbolt.org/g/P5QN2Q).

Comment: Note that [Clang also supports this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#format-gnu-format).

Comment: @DanielH Thanks! Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is very beautiful and bonus points for showing me how to use it in my member function! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio you can use [SAL annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/using-sal-annotations-to-reduce-c-cpp-code-defects) `_Printf_format_string_` macro:

```
#include <sal.h>

void log
(
    int32_t                                    log_level
,   _In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ const char * psz_format
,   ...
);
```

To make code portable you may want to define format attribute macro and SAL macros substitutions when necessary:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define ATTRIBUTE_PRINTF(format_index, vargs_index) __attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, format_index, vargs_index)))
#else
#define ATTRIBUTE_PRINTF(format_index, vargs_index)
#endif

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <sal.h>
#else
#define _In_z_
#define _Printf_format_string_
#endif

void log
(
    int32_t                                    log_level
,   _In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ const char * psz_format
,   ...
) ATTRIBUTE_PRINTF(2, 3);
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. If I declare my own function with _Printf_format_string_, I get no warnings at all, if I use standard sprintf, everything is ok. VS2017 15.9.7, <sal.h> included. any ideas?

Comment: @GeorgeHazan Perhaps warnings are suppressed or C++ Code Analysis is not executed.

Comment: when I replace my own function with printf without changing anything else, warnings are present, so it's not the problem, I've summarized the problem in a short snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826028/why-printf-format-string-macro-doesnt-produce-any-warnings

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for how to make it work on MSVC, GCC, and Clang simultaneously.

### Option 1: Use the `__attribute__` and `_Printf_format_string_`

```
// To see the warnings, extra compilation flags need to be added:
// * For the MSVC: /analyze
// * For GCC and Clang: -Wall

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define CHECK_FORMAT_STRING(format_string_index_one_based, vargs_index_one_based)       \
  __attribute__((format(printf, format_string_index_one_based, vargs_index_one_based)))
#else
#define CHECK_FORMAT_STRING(format_string_index_one_based, vargs_index_one_based)
#endif

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <sal.h>
#else
#define _Printf_format_string_
#endif

void MyFormat(_Printf_format_string_ const char *fmt, ...) CHECK_FORMAT_STRING(1, 2);
void MyFormat(_Printf_format_string_ const char *fmt, ...) {
   va_list va;
   va_start(va, fmt);
   vprintf(fmt, va);
   va_end(va);
}

int main() {
    MyFormat("Hello, %d", "World");
}
```

[Demo on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:7),source:%27//+To+see+the+warnings,+extra+compilation+flags+need+to+be+added:%0A//+*+For+the+MSVC:+/analyze%0A//+*+For+GCC+and+Clang:+-Wall%0A%0A%23include+%3Ccstdarg%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0A%23ifdef+__GNUC__%0A%23define+CHECK_FORMAT_STRING(format_string_index_one_based,+vargs_index_one_based)+++++++%5C%0A++__attribute__((format(printf,+format_string_index_one_based,+vargs_index_one_based)))%0A%23else%0A%23define+CHECK_FORMAT_STRING(format_string_index_one_based,+vargs_index_one_based)%0A%23endif%0A%0A%23if+defined(_MSC_VER)%0A%23include+%3Csal.h%3E%0A%23else%0A%23define+_Printf_format_string_%0A%23endif%0A%0Avoid+MyFormat(_Printf_format_string_+const+char+*fmt,+...)+CHECK_FORMAT_STRING(1,+2)%3B%0Avoid+MyFormat(_Printf_format_string_+const+char+*fmt,+...)+%7B%0A+++va_list+va%3B%0A+++va_start(va,+fmt)%3B%0A+++vprintf(fmt,+va)%3B%0A+++va_end(va)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++MyFormat(%22Hello,+%25d%22,+%22World%22)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:40.98896218358117,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.57403642318597,l:%274%27,m:70.25691699604744,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+9.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:29.743083003952563,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:28.955726630416702,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:/analyze,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:34.0649456901667,l:%274%27,m:70.25691699604744,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:29.743083003952563,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:30.05531118600215,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

### Option 2: Use a trick with a macros

The following trick was proposed by [Paul Groke](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-format-specifier-checking-on-user-defined/843652#T-N10148740)

```
// On GCC and Clang compiler, you need to enable the "-Wall" compilation flag

#define CHECK_FORMAT(...)                               \
    do {                                                \
        const char dummy = sizeof(printf(__VA_ARGS__)); \
        (void)dummy;                                    \
    } while (false)

#define MY_FMT(...) \
    do {                                               \
        CHECK_FORMAT(__VA_ARGS__);                     \
        MyFormat(__VA_ARGS__);                         \
    } while (false)

void MyFormat(const char *fmt, ...) {
   va_list va;
   va_start(va, fmt);
   vprintf(fmt, va);
   va_end(va);
}

int main() {
    MY_FMT("Hello, %d", "World");
}
```

[Demo on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgJykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFJdpgOmUIETMQE2T5%2BXIFVNQJ1DQTFkTFxibb1jc25bcM9faXliQCUtqhexMjsHAD06wDUAPIMWwDibm5bhuhbbgZGW2gsyXRxpFsAnktb4ZjnRFuMTNH0WwICEwW3MZgAtAB1MS0ME3VB3OhMRwCLZUAzAEwaACCWNxZgSYWQ3iwoISbmQCgI6AamIS2Dx5kJDGJXlJJnJlOpTg5DJxjIJWBo4QuAAlsG4ANIAfQAYjsAEoAWWxABUIAA6LVzLa6vX6g2Go16kwAVjceP16FQoIA7BZjY6nc6nWaLTjjWgGFSbggGlt0D4WM8yQARLbpABemFQVAgyWIYQIcel0oAatjpdiFQchKm5nMOQ63ZajRAAG6oPDoOaBljBosupvOksek228MAdwQDy21DESkL/P5gswwpBSoAmnKleqtRqda3sVabSZ7c2N5vdUvjW5xVK5YqVerUxmszm89LCwkHVuTebS4alc9ZSQWMiIKfM9nc/nG3fDR3dsux7AF%2B1oQdGRxStqy2Z9X2Id8CAgL0fWQP1iC2AAqKgWAIJ550Xe1H3LJhpVoPAfVIosSLIqkegrJgnlwghrysNstnLBMkzjFinlItjaOlVxGME/kOyg7Eky2d8wggIj2OXPUpxndUwVFTBaFoVAnnMU10DBXSzDMSESFoAzjLE3EJJxDgFloThTV4PwOC0UhUE4C1LGsCMlhWEEmR4UgCE0OyFgAaxASQNA1fwAA44v8AA2MwuDihJTTirguFtfROEkZzQvczheAUEANGC0KFjgWAYEQFAEXuegyAoFDGoeeJgC4Yy%2BDoAg4jKiBoiK6IwgaZ5OCC0bmGIZ4dmibRqhC7heFuNhBD2WgJtc3gsGiLxgDcGEypW0gsHfIxxB2s68GIJa8HLTATrczBVGqLx%2Bsm3gk00r79DwaJiHGjwsD%2BghExYL6FnRJhgAUNM8EwTsdmSRg/v4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdRrt0Lh9EMYxrGsf7ojKyAFlQZIUW9TgoRhXhUEe4hEywWn5NsTT7ucCBXDGVoggYdBpgGeJSdSdImdFvQ5cKBgpbKQZSY6JnulGTwWj0LXahGXown6dWZcmXWcjF%2BjGjV2YuAWBQ/NWCR7Mcwrro8jgtlUOKkvBJLJC2YBkGQLZuo1Mw%2B1wQgSFBAlHd4ZatALUhIskW0NVNW1ooSIPE7i01/FyhyOAK0hIdtGKzFNJL/C4evko0TPJGkFy3O90rysqnbqrqiAkCWAhkg%2B8hKFuJq4giVg1j9gOg5DsOtn8DUgs%2BOPub0DHhFEcRcZ3gm1CKknSE7IHkihvKOCc0gO/Zzgdg%2B0eCC2WNff9wPg9D8PI%2BjiAPCImagnBISde6pwWMCJgWB4h8zLhXSGZhV65wSBodKGgNAJH8KaWuSUkj32KhwbuFUU5hXTiAMwcVYqmhzmYJKeCW6N2rmYa%2BCRPadxKuAuypAapQAHkgSeHVx5tSAYMcsyBkjJGlOWNo5FkRPQINKVQQdeq0H6sQQaw1rrTXGn9HRs15qLQcH9NajACCbW2m5PaB0jpaROkFc65MrpWNuvdR6z1eCvXep9U6P0y5uQooDYGGA1huXBngSGK1oYYnhojZGqMXJBR3ljfe0hD5KGPsTChZMjAoEppYamvN6aM0yCddmnNuZPXgE7AWnQ/DCwlorUmIRTYzA1vkeWmQmkdJVvbdphsujG26QMhgOsTYlGlgbIZetxiW3GWbB2TsXY43djfdhD8fbKODiwBQ4jOJtA1AYfqPoICxyIJhQKcxk5VQiokSQGoNBB38JIOu/gNCNySqXfKvAq411eY3fwzdW7tyKl3WwPdSH93gIPEAw8X7CMEc1GebBODzy/kvX%2BZgo6ePwOc6s29ZApJxmk2QR8iZuV0Cw8%2BTBL5ROvrfAh3sn4jw%2Bm/KgvtF47L2TI1eRyFF9kAVPC5BIzBXK4WnKBMDKCrIQRQ5BkhUHoMwdg3B%2BDQWcLKiQm55DUEPJoaA7K/sMGpVNKw9ZhDrl91WWYc1YLIULE5ukZwkggA)