# why _Printf_format_string_ macro doesn't produce any warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sal

In the following snippet the wrong usage of format specifiers inside the `MyFormat()` call should produce a warning, according to SAL specifications, and for the identical call of `printf()`, I really will receive all these warnings, but my code is compiled silently even with `/W4`. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using MSVC 2017 15.9.7 Community edition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void MyFormat(_Printf_format_string_ const char *fmt, ...)
{
   va_list va;
   va_start(va, fmt);
   vprintf(fmt, va);
   va_end(va);
}

int main()
{
   printf("blabla %s\n", L"qq"); // Warnings as expected
   MyFormat("blabla %s\n", L"qq"); // No warnings :(
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nvTf4rdev)

Comment: I suspect that you have C++ code analysis disabled. For me this causes `warning C6303: Format string mismatch:  wide character string passed as _Param_(2) when character string is required in call to 'MyFormat' Actual type: 'const wchar_t [3]'.`

Comment: but why does it print a warning for printf then?
I don't use VS, I just feed this small file to cl.exe

Comment: C++ code analysis adds a lot of other controls and slow down the compiling process. on gcc works from 2000, why on 2019 there is no support on visual studio?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the `/analyze` flag will cause this to [produce a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/rbaxi3). However it is a different (and in my opinion inferior) warning than what you would get from `printf`. Unfortunately I can't find a way to make a user-defined function to produce that style of warning.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this headscratcher myself, and for me it was because the warnings were all explicitly disabled. (eg 6340, 6284, 6273.) printf emits *different* warnings (4477) which were not disabled.

Without seeing OP's full command-line, it's impossible to know if that was their problem, but to anyone else going through this: check your /wd flags.